# Where is mod_passenger.so, installed with yum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache, passenger

I have a combo of Centos 6-Apache-Passenger-Ruby. Install was made following instructions [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/apache/oss/el6/install_passenger.html). I also have whm, which means changes to httpd.conf must be made by click. While trying to include `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf`, tells me there is an error because: `Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_passenger.so into server.`

Problem is this line at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf`:

```
LoadModule passenger_module modules/mod_passenger.so
```

Last part of the sentence should point to actual `mod_passenger.so`, that is not inside `/etc/httpd/modules`... Problem is where it is?

I installed via yum, which means:

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release pygpgme curl
sudo curl --fail -sSLo /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/definitions/el-passenger.repo
sudo yum install -y mod_passenger
```

When I run `sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install`, it does not matter in which apache install (already run them all), says the following:

```
   You did not specify 'LoadModule passenger_module' in any of your
   Apache configuration files. This means that Phusion Passenger
   for Apache is not installed or not active. Please run the
   Phusion Passenger Apache module installer:

      /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module --apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs
```

I run the installer, says all is ok, but never works...

I know I have to specify the location of the location like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /path/to/the/module
```

But I can not find it. locate mod_passenger.so does not work. And I can not go to the .rvm location because is not there. Passenger is not install as gem, but via yum...

Any trick to find where passenger is locating the `mod_passenger.so`? Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution find / -type f -name mod_passenger.so... Thanks to http://serverfault.com/questions/139790/apache2-server-does-not-start-cannot-pen-shared-object-file

Comment: `find` is nice and thorough but it consumes a lot more I/O, CPU, and clock time than the `rpm` solution I show below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpm` will give you a list of files for any installed package like so:

```
rpm -ql mod_passenger
```

and this can be refined further by `grep`ing for just your file:

```
rpm -ql mod_passenger | grep 'so$'
```

A full example with a different apache module package is:

```
$ rpm -ql mod_ssl
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
/var/cache/httpd/ssl
$ rpm -ql mod_ssl | grep 'so$'
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
```